# How do you pass params in a link_to without breaking if a required key is not present?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, parameters

First of all, I got this working but I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

I have verious index pages where users can apply filters and then export the results to `.csv` or `.xls` files.

What I do is forward whatever `params` are present (after the filters have been applied) to the controller action where the DB is queried again and the results sent to the service that builds the file, like so:

*link_to:*

```
      <li>
        <% if params.dig(:q).present? %>
          <%= link_to export_payments_admin_payments_path(params: { q: params.require(:q).permit(params[:q].keys, status_in: [], payment_type_in: [])}, format: "csv") do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Export
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to export_payments_admin_payments_path(format: "csv") do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Export
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
```

*controller action:*

```
  def export_payments
    @pre_search = current_account.payments.includes(:user)
    @search = @pre_search.ordered.ransack(params[:q])
    @payments = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv do
        send_data FileManager::PaymentsExporter.new(@payments).call,
                  filename: "payments_#{Date.today}" + ".csv"
      end
    end
  end
```

The thing is that as you can tell, the `link_to` has to be wrapped in a conditional because if I `require(:q)` but it's not present (no filters were applied) the view breaks as the required `:q` key is not present.

Is there a better way to do this? I've tried removing the `require(:q)` but no params are passed at all if I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all this logic to the controller or a helper.

Start by creating a method to mount the params sent inside the link so you don't need to wrap it into a conditional

```
# controller

def export_payments
  ...
  @q_params = q_params
  ...
end

def q_params
  if params.dig(:q).present?
    params.require(:q).permit(params[:q].keys, status_in: [], payment_type_in: [])
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

And then, use the method to render the link:

```
# view

<%= link_to export_payments_admin_payments_path(format: "csv", params: { q: @q_params }) do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Export
<% end %>
```

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 Keep in mind that depending on your architecture these methods may live in other places besides `controllers` or `helpers`. This is just an example of how to extract the logic from the views :)